# SignalR JS Client no communication from client to server

Tags: signalr

I have two apps under same domain http://mydomain.com/App1 & http://mydomain.com/App2 configured with SignalR.

i have my hub class(server asp.net c# class) setup at App1. 
And i have my signalR javascript clients setup at App1 and App2. 
For App2 i am connecting to hub, setup at App1 (included in my Index html file as javascript src=/mydomain/App1/SignalR/hubs).

When i try to send a message from server to clients (app1 & app2), i am able to see it only in app1 and not in app2. But when i send a message from client app2 to server app1 i am able to get that message in app1.

There is only one-way comm. from client to server. Any reasons why is it so?

Comment: Are you handling server RPC calls in your clients?

Comment: Yes i am. i am following the samples from ASP.net getting started with SignalR 2.0 samples.

Comment: Are you sending the message to all clients on the Server or just Callers.Others or something like that.